# Setting custom axis values on sparkline

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set custom values in my sparkline, however, I keep getting a `Run-time error: Object doesn't support this property or method`.  Where am I going wrong in my `.Custom` value section?

```
    With spark
        .Points.Markers.Visible = True
        .Points.Markers.Color.Color = vbBlack
        .CustomMinScaleValue = -0.1 'error thrown here
        .CustomMaxScaleValue = 1.2 'error will most likely be thrown here
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CustomMinScaleValue property can be returned or set only when the
>   MinScaleType property of the specified SparkVerticalAxis object is set
>   to xlSparkScaleCustom (3).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194837.aspx

Similar issue for `CustomMaxScaleValue`

Untested:

```
With spark

    .Points.Markers.Visible = True
    .Points.Markers.Color.Color = vbBlack

    .Axes.Vertical.MinScaleType = xlSparkScaleCustom '<<<
    .CustomMinScaleValue = -0.1 

    .Axes.Vertical.MaxScaleType = xlSparkScaleCustom '<<<
    .CustomMaxScaleValue = 1.2 

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am still having trouble as to how this looks in practice.  The link you provided gives me the answer, but what would it look in practice?

Comment: Scratch that...figured it out.  Thanks.